# Plugin not loaded on ionic deploy

Tags: javascript, deployment, ionic-framework

I am trying to get updates with ionic deploy, I added all packages and added to

`app.js $ionicDeploy`

but get an error on:

```
$ionicDeploy.check().then(function(response) {
```

the error the I get is:

```
“Plugin not loaded”
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your deploy code wrapped in a

```
$ionicPlatform.ready
```

function.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that ionic deploy [is not designed to work on browsers](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/deploy-from-scratch)

There is a thread about this in the ionic forums:

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/deploy-ionic-app-as-a-website/2845/18

A possible solution is found [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/deploy-ionic-app-as-a-website/2845/17#ember1869)